# Why are only some "u" words pronounced with a glide in American English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels

In most words with a long U that doesn't start a syllable, it is pronounced /uː/. Examples: *student, reduce, introduce*. However, in some words (such as *music, mule, human*) it is pronounced /juː/. I've heard that in other countries, even the first examples are pronounced like the second (/ˈstjuːd(ə)nt/, /ɹɪˈdjuːs/, /ɪntrəˈdjuːs/).

What's with the discrepancies in the American pronunciation?

Comment: One classic split involves the word _coupon_, which some speakers pronounce "coo-pon" and others "Q-pon."

Comment: See [yod-dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping) for your perusal. There’s a _lot_ of data and conditioning going on here—it’s quite complex and not at all easy to tabulate or follow which dialects drop which yods. There are even a few dialects here and there that do drop the yods in _music_ and _mule_ (and even _use_, so that it rhymes with _ooze_!). Never heard of any dialects that drop the one in _you_, making it rhyme with _ooh_, though.

Comment: I know you've tagged it as `american-english` but all those words would be pronounced with _you_ in almost every British accent (with the possible exclusion of a heavy Belfast accent who still wouldn't use 'oo'). Australian's would pronounce it as _you_, slightly extended and South African (English) would be _you_ but clipped a bit. Is it possible that those areas where it is pronounced _you_ are heavily influenced by British accents? Do you know where that pronunciation is common (in the US)?

Comment: @Frank most places afaik.

Comment: I meant 'styou-dent' is not just common but standard in the UK, while 'stood-ent' is the US pronunciation I know from people from all parts of the US (I don't do IPA either). What I meant when I asked 'where?' was where in the US are those words pronounced the same as in the UK.

Comment: @Frank I've clarified the question a bit. The "other regions" were outside of the US.

Comment: Ah - I understood it as 'regions inside the US'. _youtube_ is a good example : US Pronunciation is generally 'you-toob', UK is generally either 'you-tyoub' or 'you-chube'. See JBJs yod-dropping link above.

Comment: @Frank: I'm not sure there is any region in the US where all these words are consistently pronounced the same as in the UK. Note that yod-dropping is not an all-or-nothing proposition. For example, I keep yods after 'n's and in most words starting with 'd' (e.g. I drop them in *dude* and *dual* but not in *duel*), but I usually drop them after 't'. And I can't even pronounce them in a word starting with 'st' without quite a bit of effort. So there may be a lot more Americans who say *stoodent* than say *nooz*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, **u:** (or "oo") is predominantly used in American English, whereas **ju:** (yoo) is preferred in British English. However, variations exist, and for the case of student, their data shows that around 90% of American English speakers say **u:**. (Edited)

On page 850, you can find the following "rules":

> In the case of expected **ju:**, **juə**, **ju**, the **j** drops out
>   as follows:
>
> - after the consonant sounds **tʃ**, **dʒ**, **ʃ**, **r**, **j** as in jury, rude
> - sometimes in BrE, and always in AmE, after **l**, **θ**, **s**, **z** as in assume
> - usually in AmE, but not in BrE, after **t**, **d**, **n** as in tune

Comment: That can't be right. I know of no British accent that would pronounce student as 'stood-ent' and I've not yet met an American who says 'styou-dent'. All the words the question author has listed are pronounced with _you_ in most British accents.

Comment: The Longman Dictionary is one of the most reliable resources. The non-standard pronunciations are not very common, but according to research they do exist.

Comment: Nope, sorry to disagree with Longman but current US pronunciation is overwhelmingly "stoodent".  "Styudent" sounds like a dialect of times gone by, like in the movies from the 1940's maybe.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Interesting. The book does not provide information about when the data were collected.

Comment: I'm British, and I can confirm that in all but the most rustic accents (e.g. strong Norfolk or West Country) it is "styoudent".  I haven't seen any mention yet of the Irish pronunciation of "column", which retains the 'yod', rendering it as "colyum".

Comment: If this is indeed how they write it, they are flat-out contradicting themselves. The last point in the list is correct: after dentals, the yod is usually dropped in AmE (stoodent, toon), and usually retained in BrE (styudent, tyune). Either Longman somehow switched BrE and AmE in the bit you quote in the first paragraph, or you did when quoting it—at any rate, it's exactly backwards.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Dear all, I just realized that I had indeed written ju: instead of u: at the end of the first para. Apologies for the confusion. Now I see why you all pointed out that something was wrong. In my head, I was always claiming that most Americans say u:, in accordance with Longman. Therefore, I thought the argument was about whether it is even more than 90%. I have edited the answer accordingly. The actual numbers given in the book are 88% u:, 12% ju:.

Comment: It still seems very odd that they claim that [u:] is predominantly British and [ju:] predominantly American (as the first sentence still says)—quite contrary to actual practice.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also fixed now, and feeling embarrassed. Longman does not make that claim. I would post a photograph of the page, but not sure if that is OK with respect to copyright?

Comment: Makes much more sense now!